# How to downgrade feature branch installed LXD to LTS branch?

Tags: lxd

In order to get a more recent feature I upgraded lxd to the feature branch using:

`sudo apt install lxd lxd-client`

I have however experienced instability since and would like to switch back to the LTS branch.

How to switch back to the LTS branch (without purging) as there are containers which already exist?

Comment: which version of Ubuntu Server are you using ? do you Install LXD from your distro or from a PPA ?

Comment: Using Ubuntu 16.04LTS and installed it from the distro

Answer (score 0):

if you are using LXD in Xenial (16.04LTS) then you can check:

```
~$ apt-cache show lxd | grep Version 
Version: 2.16-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04.1
Version: 2.0.10-0ubuntu1~16.04.1
Version: 2.0.2-0ubuntu1~16.04.1
Version: 2.0.0-0ubuntu4
~$
```

If your actual version is 2.0.x, then you need the update and you will not have any compatibility problem, Because 2.16 come from backports and by default this updates don't apply.

But, if you are updated now to 2.16 release (this one comes from **xenial-backports**), then you can't downgrade to 2.0 version cleanly, because lxd 2.1x get new functionality with **network** and **storage** functions/modules, and this update the sqlite databases used by lxd.

The updates from backports try to work without any problem in upgrade. If you added the PPAs from LXD, these don't guarantee any compatibility in upgrades.

check this for similar cases:

https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/install-specific-lxd-version-in-ubuntu-16-04-2/247
https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/2952